# Make a image as button and not downloadable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make an image button that can't be downloaded via right-click and 'save as'.

Also I have a hover javascript, that changes the image.

I tried CSS:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

But if I do that, the image doesn't change when I hover over it.

My hover Javascript:

```
function hoverButton(element, src) { 
  element.setAttribute('src', src);
}

function unhoverButton(element, src) {
  element.setAttribute('src', src);
}
```

And in my image html:

```
<a href="../login/"><img class="headButton" src="img/loginBtn.png" onmouseover="hoverButton(this, 'img/loginBtnDark.png');" onmouseout="unhoverButton(this, 'img/loginBtn.png');"></a>
```

I know it's a bit long but it does the job.

I also tried to use some javascript to make the button image not downloadable via right click.

```
$('img').mousedown(function (e)) {
  if(e.button == 2) { // right click
    return false; // do nothing!
  }
}
```

Does somebody know what I have to do?

Comment: you can really only inconvience people and never really stop them from `saving` it ~ afterall if it is in the browser then it is on their computer already! Any method in the browser to prevent right-click would rely upon Javascript - if the user does not allow javascript then it will be negated.

Comment: If your page is on the Web then there is almost nothing you can do to restrict access to the assets that make up the page. I'm not sure what would be so special about this image that it needs such special care.

Comment: you might try `document.querySelector('img').oncontextmenu=(event)=>{ return false; }`

Comment: You could set the image as a background on the button element, that would mean right-click wouldn't work. But again, it's still possible to download it by inspecting the code and viewing the CSS to get the image URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option, using a `background-image` instead of an `img`, which would mean the user can't right-click to save the image.

It's still possible to get the image, just not with right-click.

```css
button {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

button:hover {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Alternate);
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```